# windows 7 64 bit reinstall on an ssd

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have an ocz vertex plus r2 ata ssd drive, I want to insert my windows 7 disc and completely wipe the hard drive. Do I have to partition anything or will windows disc do everything for me? Will the windows disc completely wipe the SSD? I an a novice and no nothing about creating partitions or changing bios or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 will partition the hd for you, in very easy steps. I am fairly certain it will overwrite any MBR entry, and so wipe your hds. This would only be important if you'd consider dual booting with another OS, which it doesn't sound you plan to. As long as your DVD drive works fine, all you need to do is plug the W7 cd in, and follow steps that are all pretty self-explanatory. Just make sure your boot sequence has the DVD drive first: after starting your computer, hit F2 (or, on almost all comps, F10), go to Boot, read the description and make DVD first.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to start afresh, for best results use the [OCZ Bootable Tools](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?95888-Bootable-Tools-for-OCZ-Vertex-2-3-Agility2-3-Solid3-Revo-and-Ibis-SSD-s&p=691605&viewfull=1#post691605) and [secure erase](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?95888-Bootable-Tools-for-OCZ-Vertex-2-3-Agility2-3-Solid3-Revo-and-Ibis-SSD-s&p=691608&viewfull=1#post691608) the drive:

   [image: 1]
2. Boot from Win7 DVD and install as usual (it will handle partitioning for you, but if you need to create extra data partitions you'll have to do so manually - there are lots of guides on the net for this).

Comment: Hi @Karan, I was just wondering what the benefit of step 1 is. Is it performance related?

Comment: @Louis: You can quick format as well (full format is not recommended), but if you want to restore an SSD to (almost) fresh-out-of-the-box condition a secure erase is best. Shouldn't do it too often though.